# How to fix too many redirects after enabling SSL and creating a new self certificate

Tags: certificate

The website is working in HTTPS. But the problem occurs when trying to access `/sitecore`, the login page does not load and instead is getting redirected to `/sitecore/client/Applications/LicenseOptions/StartPage` and there is a message saying redirected you too many times.

This happened after enabling SSL in the solution and creating a new self certificate.

Comment: Have you tried to contact with Sitecore Support? Any answer from them?